# Стилизация объектов через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, style

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку увеличивался шрифт текста. Пример:

```js
styling(){
var fsize = document.getElementById('myText').value; // принимаем значение инпута

document.getElementById('myText').style.fontSize = fsize; // применяем значение с инпута(переменной) для стилизации текста
}
```

```html
<p id="myText"> hello world </p>
<input type="number" value="18" min="8" max="28">
<input type="submit" onclick="styling()">
```

Вопрос: почему не применяется стилизация к тексту? Сам OnClick - работает, но не применяется именно стилизация. Где у меня ошибка или как еще можно это реализовать?

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что у вас у `<input type="nuber">` нет `id`? Вы явно именно у него пытаетесь взять `value`, но указываете id другого элемента ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде три ошибки

1. В объявлении функции `styling()` пропущено слово `function`
2. Вы пытаетесь вытащить значение из параграфа, а не из инпута
3. Вы не указываете единиц измерения для размера

```js
function styling() {
  var fsize = document.getElementById('mySize').value; // принимаем значение инпута
  document.getElementById('myText').style.fontSize = fsize + "pt"; // применяем значение с инпута(переменной) для стилизации текста
}
```

```html
<p id="myText"> hello world </p>
<input type="number" id="mySize" value="18" min="8" max="28">
<input type="submit" onclick="styling()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых вы пытаетесь взять значение для для размера шрифта из параграфа с текстом. Я думаю Вы хотели бы его получить из инпута

Во вторых задавать размер нужно с указанием единиц измерения

```js
const styling = () => {
  const fsize = document.getElementById('value').value;
  const text = document.getElementById('myText');
  text.style.fontSize = fsize + 'px';
}
```

```html
<p id="myText">hello world </p>
<input id="value" type="number" value="18" min="8" max="28">
<input type="submit" onclick="styling()">
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде вы берете `value` в элемента `p`, в которого нет такого свойства. Если вы напишите, например, вот так:

```
document.getElementById('myText').style.fontSize = '18px';
```

то шрифт поменяется.